# inotifywait - pause monitoring while executing command

Tags: inotify, inotifywait

I have the following command:

```
inotifywait -q -m -e modify,create,delete,move -r /path/to/dir | while read; do custom_command; done
```

This is running on the server. On my local, I'm doing an rsync up to the server. So, when the rsync runs, the inotifywait fires off the custom_command. This works.

Here's the trick: custom_command modifies files within the directory being monitored, which, of course, causes inotifywait to fire off the command again, and it goes in a loop.

Is there a way to pause inotifywait while the custom_command is running?

Comment: What if a new file would appear in the moment when inotifywatch is paused?

Comment: In this case, I'm fine if it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue too, and I couldn't find answer, but instead of pausing I created while loop and removed the monitor mode (it stops when an event is called), and restarts because of endless while loop.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    echo "Listener started"
    inotifywait -q -r . | if read DIRECTORY EVENT FILE; then
        echo "Event: $EVENT | Directory: $DIRECTORY | File: $FILE"
        sleep 5s
        echo "Triggered"
    fi
    echo "Listener ended"
done
```

In your case it should be like this:

```
while : do inotifywait -q -e modify,create,delete,move -r /path/to/dir | if read; then custom_command; fi done
```

P. S. I might make syntax errors, check the code before getting it into production.